# Enquire and inquire

Tags: american-english, british-english, synonyms, orthography

In British English I think these two words have different shades of meaning, but I couldn't articulate them. In American English I see inquire used where I would use "enquire".

Are there shades of meaning in British English?

Do they exist in American English?

Comment: I am convinced the difference was creating by grammatical fanatics trying to ret-con two meanings rather than have two acceptable spellings for a word: one having French (en-) and the other being Latin (in-) prefixes to "query".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [Oxford Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/enquire) has an "Help box" regarding Enquire vs Inquire, I'll paste it here:

> In *British English* people sometimes distinguish between *enquire* and *inquire*, using **enquire** for the general meaning of ‘ask for information’ and **inquire** for the more particular meaning of ‘officially investigate’.
>
> - "*I called to enquire about train times.*"
> - "*A committee will inquire into the allegations.*"
>
> However, you can use either spelling in either meaning. In *American English* inquire is usually used in both meanings.

The NOAD distinguishes them as *inquire* and *inquiry* being the usual U.S. spellings, while *enquire* and *enquiry* are classified as "*the standard forms in Britain*".

Comment: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/enquire-or-inquire

Comment: It works now because I updated it myself. :)

Answer (score 7):

You almost always want enquire in the sense of "ask", eg "I enquired when the bus would leave"
Inquire is only used in the sense of an inquiry - an official investigation into something. eg. "Police inquire into the cause of the accident".

However my AE setting spellchecker doesn't think that "enquire" is a word - so this may be a British English distinction.

Comment: +1 Better provide some source of reference.

Comment: I think @Alenanno gave a better answer anyway

Comment: You know  the ELU conventions, and the difference between an answer and a comment.