# Unsure whether to use "enquire" or "inquire"

Tags: word-choice

I have read the post [Enquire and inquire](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27162/enquire-and-inquire). It was illuminating, but I am unsure which version to use. I am an American, but am writing to a woman in England. It is a formal business letter, and the context is: "I am writing to *enquire*..." Is this appropriate, as I believe it fits the criteria mentioned in the other post, or should I use *inquire*?

Comment: Based on the other question/answer, I recommend using _enquire_. In the future, feel free to ask specific usage cases in [chat]. :)

Comment: Thank you! I am new to this website and was not aware of the chat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost certainly OP should be *writing to enquire*, since he's presumably writing to ask about something, but *not* in the context of an official inquiry.

To the extent that there are two different words (and, frankly, many people don't distinguish), *inquire* conveys more a sense of *formal, official investigation*.

It's unlikely OP's correspondent would make that distinction and be alarmed if he wrote *inquire* (or indeed, be concerned about OP's vocabulary), but better safe than sorry – if in doubt, use *enquire*.